# uwsgi + nginx configuration - nginx not connected to uwsgi

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am having trouble trying to configure nginx with uwsgi.

I start uwsgi by:

```
uwsgi --plugin python,http --socket 127.0.0.1:8080 --wsgi-file hello.py --callable app --master
```

nginx.conf:

```
upstream uwsgicluster {
                server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {

        # Running port
        listen 80;

        # Settings to by-pass for static files
        location /static/  {
            alias /home/ubuntu/projects/conradlabs_wow/wowcFlask/static/;
        }
        # Proxying connections to application servers
        location / {
            include            uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass         uwsgicluster;
        }
}
```

I still get the default nginx homepage when I hit the ip, instead of my webpage.

I have primarily followed the steps mentioned [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-applications-using-uwsgi-web-server-with-nginx)

Comment: Can you see the site running on localhost:8080 with curl? I would suggest that this config file is not being loaded

Comment: yes the app deployed on uwsgi is accessible on port 8080 (when i use --http 0.0.0.0:8080 I can access the webpage anywhere), on port 80 however the default nginx homepage is served, instead of the app running on uwsgi 8080.

Comment: How have you installed Nginx? Also where is the vhost config before located?

Answer (score 0):

edit `nginx.conf` or `/etc/nginx/vhosts.d/example.conf`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;


    location / {
        include            uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass         127.0.0.1:8080;

        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

Restart nginx.